# How to reset a built-in symbol to its default definition?

Tags: packages, customization, built-in-symbols, system-variables

I'm trying to add functionality to some of Mathematica's built-in functions in a package I'm building. I'm not trying to overwrite any functionality—just add it where it isn't already defined.

I start my package body with:

```
Unprotect["packagename`*"];
ClearAll["packagename`*"]
```

Clearly, though, I don't want to clear the system definition! However, I do want to reset the symbol to its default system definition before adding my definition, and I don't know how to do that.

I'd also appreciate any advice on best practices for adding this functionality! I'm willing to just use a typical `:=`, but if there are better ways, I'd certainly be interested.

Comment: An example of a built-in function, and how and why you want to modify it would be helpful.

Comment: Sure! Concretely, I need to extend interval arithmetic to complex numbers. For example, something I might want to include in a package could be `Interval[n_Complex] := (#1 + #2*I) & @@ (Interval /@ ReIm[n])`. Without this, `Interval[n]` where `n` has head `Complex` doesn't evaluate to anything. Unprotecting Interval and evaluating this works—I just want to do it safely and repeatedly in a package, which I think would involve resetting `Interval` to the system default somehow.

Comment: "I need to extend interval arithmetic to complex numbers" - this isn't your question anymore, but: look up disk arithmetic. Disks are more natural to operate on than rectangles for complex numbers.

Comment: @J.M. Disk arithmetic may be more useful in delivering tighter error bounds, but there is a price in implementation difficulty.

Comment: @Daniel, yes, I've seen from the literature that there are a lot of subtleties to fret about. I presume this is why *Mathematica* doesn't have it?

Comment: @J.M. I think so, at least for significance arithmetic. But I am not certain. For `Interval`, we only really implemented real intervals, so anything with complex values becomes a rectangle of real intervals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the System` symbol you want to modify is a kernel function, then you can just use [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear) to reset it to its default state. For your [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) example:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[Interval]
```

> Language`DefinitionList[Interval->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{Protected}}]

shows that [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) has no *Values. Using [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear) on [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) will only clear new definitions that you add. Example:

```
Unprotect[Interval];
Interval[n_Complex] := (#1 + #2*I) & @@ (Interval /@ ReIm[n])
Protect[Interval];
```

Now, let's check:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[Interval]
```

> Language`DefinitionList[Interval->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{HoldPattern[Interval[n_Complex]]:>(#1+#2 I&)@@Interval/@ReIm[n]},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{Protected}}]

Notice that your definition shows up in the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) rule. Let's clear definitions:

```
Unprotect[Interval];
Clear[Interval]
Protect[Interval];
```

And the definition is gone:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[Interval]
```

> Language`DefinitionList[Interval->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{Protected}}]

Note the Interval still works:

```
Sin[Interval[{0, Pi}]]
```

> Interval[{0, 1}]